# sqlite3_column_text returned data gets corrupted during finalize/close

Tags: c, sqlite

I'm not sure what's happening here but I'm finding that the returned data from sqlite3_column_text is being altered during the finalize/close sqlite stage.

```
  // rc not handled in this abbreviated code

  sqlite3 *db;
  sqlite3_stmt *stmt;
  char * sql;

  const char * tail;
  int rc;

  char * dbName = "C:\\db\\myblobs.db";
  int myIndex = 0;

  char * myLocation1;
  string myLocation2;   

  rc = sqlite3_open(dbName, &db);

  sql = "SELECT location FROM blobs WHERE key = ?";
  rc = sqlite3_prepare(db, sql, strlen(sql), &stmt, &tail);
  sqlite3_bind_int(stmt, 1, myIndex);
  rc = sqlite3_step(stmt);

  myLocation1 = (char*)sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 0);
  myLocation2 = (char*)sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 0);

  // can process myLocation1 & myLocation2 fine here

  sqlite3_finalize(stmt); // data myLocation1 points to get corrupted
  sqlite3_close(db);      // data myLocation2 points to gets further corrupted
```

The problem is in relation to myLocation1. The data it points to is fine until it hits the sqlite3_finalize and sqlite3_close statements. However mylocation2 remains unaltered. So not sure what's happening here. After executing sqlite3_close(db), myLocation1 is identified as a "Bad Ptr" within Visual Studio 2010.

Any help most appreciated.

Answer (score 14):

From the [fine manual](http://www.sqlite.org/capi3ref.html#sqlite3_column_blob):

> `const unsigned char *sqlite3_column_text(sqlite3_stmt*, int iCol);`
>   [...]
>   The pointers returned are valid until a type conversion occurs as described above, or until `sqlite3_step()` or `sqlite3_reset()` or `sqlite3_finalize()` is called.

So as soon as you call `sqlite3_finalize`, the return values from `sqlite3_column_text` become invalid and your `myLocation1` and `myLocation2` pointers point to garbage.

If you need those strings after you call `sqlite3_finalize` then you'll have to copy them into memory that you control. In fact, due to the *are valid until a type conversion occurs* note, you should copy them immediately and only use `(char*)sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 0);` while you're making your own copies.

Comment: Thanks so much for that. And there it was, right at the bottom of the "Result Values From A Query" section. Ashamed to say I never read down that far, but that's no excuse on my part. Well it all makes sense now as sqlite needs to unallocate memory it constructed in the first place via pointers, much like malloc/free. Thank you again!