# my sqlite3 c function is leaking memory

Tags: c, memory-leaks, sqlite

Any idea why this function is leaking memory every time I call it?

```
char *getData(sqlite3 *db)
{
    char *ret;
    sqlite3_stmt *res;

    int rc = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, SELECT_STATEMENT_SQL, -1, &res, 0);

    if (rc != SQLITE_OK) {
        sprintf(stderr, "%s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
        return stderr;
    }    

    rc = sqlite3_step(res);

    if (rc == SQLITE_ROW) {
        ret = sqlite3_column_text(res, 0);

    } else {
        ret = "error!";
    }
    sqlite3_free(res);
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: I don't know sqlite (I know some others) but see you prepare a statement or cursor but see you nowhere give it the SELECT statement to execute (often text/a string). Is that correct? Further, printing to stderr as a string seems wrong; stderr is a file descriptor. No warnings? Did you declare stderr as a string and you dont use <stdio.h>?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to call [sqlite3_finalize()](http://sqlite.org/c3ref/finalize.html) to properly release memory, allocated for the statement.

Comment: This fixes the memory leak but for some reason my return value is now empty

Comment: NVM the last comment, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8798825/sqlite3-column-text-returned-data-gets-corrupted-during-finalize-close helped me figure the rest