# How retray a field text from SQLite

Tags: sqlite

I am dealing with SQLite (on ESP32 board) and I would extract text field:

```
    ...          
    if (sqlite3_step(res) == SQLITE_ROW) {
      const unsigned char * Auth = sqlite3_column_text(res, 0);
      const unsigned char  * Cite = sqlite3_column_text(res, 1);
      sqlite3_finalize(res);
      sqlite3_close(db);
      response->printf("%s\n%s",Auth,Cite);
    }
    ...
```

Instead of receiving, for example:

Alan Kay

You probably know that arrogance, in computer science, is measured in nanodijkstras.

I receive:

���? Kay

���?probably know that arrogance, in computer science, is measured in nanodijkstras.

I think that there is a length in front of text but I don't know how deal with sqlite3_column_bytes.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I apologize, I found a clue on [sqlite3_column_text returned data gets corrupted during finalize/close](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8798825/sqlite3-column-text-returned-data-gets-corrupted-during-finalize-close).
I deplaced **sqlite3_finalize(res);** **and sqlite3_close(db);**

```
    ...
    response->printf("%s\n%s",Auth,Cite);
    request->send(response);
    sqlite3_finalize(res);
    sqlite3_close(db);
    ...
```

So I receive a correct answere like:

Alan Perlis

A language that doesn't affect the way you think about programming is not worth knowing.

Best regards

Giovanni Rossati